# 3D Images / Stereoscopy in Beamer

Tags: beamer, 3d

Is it possible to create "real" 3D effects within a Beamer presentation using Stereoscopy (for 3D monitors)?

What I mean by that is:

- Duplicate the slides left and right (for both eyes)
- Animations so that certain parts of the slide pop out of the screen, i.e. different translation in the left and right view
- Support for stereoscopic images, or even videos (with the multimedia or movie package).
  An example for a stereoscopic image:

[image: Simple stereoscopic image]

Is there a package that allows creating these kinds of effects? Or a workaround with the normal Beamer package? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Personally I do not think that exists a specific package for what you ask.

Comment: The cheapest option: `\usepackage{graphicx}`+`\includegraphics{...}` and cross-eyed looking at the result (at your own risk).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the ideas.
I think I wasn't clear enough: the 3D images are the simple part. The difficult part is to duplicate the slides (with text, equations, ...) for the left and right eye.
The monitor doesn't use analygraphics (red-cyan), but two completely different images side by side. (polarization glasses)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options, none of them using a special package:

1. Just include the original image (`\includegraphics{...}`), and look at it in a cross-eyed fashion. This might be a bit painful, thus do it at your own risk. However, special prismatic goggles are available in order to avoid cross-eying.

[image]

---

2. Produce an [↗**anaglyph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D) from the two halves of the original, embed it into the document (`\includegraphics{...}`) and use cheap **red-cyan goggles** to look at it. These are the steps for creating such an anaglyph using [↗ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) command line tool `magick`:

2.1. Get the original size:

```
$ magick identify 92vc6.jpg
92vc6.jpg JPEG 3232x1080 3232x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 232083B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

2.2. Save the left half (for the right eye) and the right half (for the left eye) into separate files:

```
$ magick convert -crop 1616x1080+0+0 92vc6.jpg shark-right.png
$ magick convert -crop 1616x1080+1616+0 92vc6.jpg shark-left.png
```

2.3. Produce the anaglyph by compositing the red channel of `shark-left.png` and the green and blue channels of `shark-right.png` into one image file `shark-ana.png`:

```
$ magick composite -stereo +0 shark-right.png shark-left.png shark-ana.png
```

If you have a sequence of anaglyphs (set of PNG or JPEG, or animated gif) making up an animation, you could embed this sequence using the `animate` package. The same applies to animated pairs of stereo images (like the above) where you may want to use prismatic goggles (or cross-eying).

**`shark-ana.png`**:

[image]

Comment: Cross-eye is really low conf yet very efficient!

Comment: Hi AlexG, thanks for the idea. But the monitor uses two completely different images for the left and right eye, arranged horizontally side by side, and then uses polarization glasses. I'm not looking for an analygraph.

Comment: Ok, for this you will have to prepare two versions of the presentation PDF, one with the left-eye, the other with the right-eye images.  Then, you will have to join them somehow.